# MYSQL SUM(IF) with group by NAME but some NAME wanna makes sum

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, count

I have one question in SQL.

This is the query.

```
SELECT Customer,
        SUM(IF(date_format(OutputDate, '%Y') = 2020 AND date_format(OutputDate, '%m') = 3, SupplyPrice, 0)) AS March
    FROM (SELECT Customer, OutputDate, SupplyPrice FROM `TableOutput`) AS C
    GROUP BY Customer
    ORDER BY March DESC
  LIMIT 20;
```

it makes a result below:

```
Customer       March
A              100
B              200
C              300
D              400
...
```

but I wanna make Customer A and B sum together as A(not B) or new name(e.g. Z)

like this:

```
Customer       March
A(or Z)        300
C              300
D              400
...
```

I want to modify the query and output it.

Comment: So you only want to sum customer A and B together into Z, or do you wanno do this for the other values too? Like (C + D) = X, (E+F) Y, etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand that you want to group together customers `A` and `B`. You can do this with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN customer IN ('A', 'B') THEN 'A' ELSE Customer
     END) as real_customer,
    SUM(CASE WHEN outputDate >= '2020-03-01' AND outputDate < '2020-04-01' THEN SupplyPrice ELSE 0 END) AS March
FROM `TableOutput`
GROUP BY real_customer
ORDER BY March DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Note that I modified the date predicate on `outputDate` so it uses comparisons to date litterals rather than using date functions; this is a more efficient approach, that may take advantage of a possibly existing index.

Comment: I really respect you. Thank you. It has been a great help.

Comment: A and B to X,   C and D to Y ... and so on
What should I do if I have a lot of conditions to show?

Comment: @Mark: you can expand the `case` expression, like:
`CASE WHEN customer in ('A', 'B') THEN 'Z' WHEN customer in ('C', 'D') THEN 'Y' ... ELSE customer END`

Comment: CASE
      WHEN Customer IN ('A', 'B') THEN 'X'
      WHEN Customer IN ('C', 'D') THEN 'Y'
      ELSE Customer
      END CustomerRearranged,  >>> Thanks for your help~!

Comment: @GMB . . . I usually align the `end` under the `case` so such things are visible.  I'll make the change here, which you can undo if you like.